# Seleccionar un valor y aumentarlo en uno (Select y Update al mismo tiempo) PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Necesito **seleccionar un valor** que almaceno en mi BD como referencia al siguiente "número" pero **a la vez aumentarlo** para que su función tenga sentido. *Por ejemplo: Seleccionar las visitas de una página y a la vez hacer que aumenten en uno (por si no se ha entendido con mi caso)* y todo esto, **en la misma sentencia**.

```
SELECT visitas FROM articulos WHERE id = 1;

UPDATE articulos SET visitas = visitas + 1 WHERE id = 1;
```

¿Se podría hacer en una única sentencia?

Comment: puedes subir tus tablas?

Comment: @Synay Creo que no hace falta, mi caso es un poco diferente pero imagina que es ese, y que quiero seleccionar un valor (INT) y a la vez aumentarlo en 1. ¿Es posible hacerlo y ahorrar recursos o lo hago en 2 sentencias?

Comment: no existe una query que haga update y select al mismo tiempo, estas haciendo bien en 2 querys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal y como ha dicho [ronpy](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/342776/seleccionar-un-valor-y-aumentarlo-en-uno-select-y-update-al-mismo-tiempo-php-m#comment620135_342776) y para cerrar esta pregunta dejando una respuesta de referencia para quienes visiten este post:

**NO se puede hacer un SELECT y aumentar o realizar cualquier otro tipo de UPDATE en una sola sentencia.**

Es totalmente válido y correcto realizarlo en 2 sentencias.

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas hacer 2 consultas, porque ya tienes la información necesaria para aplicar la actualización:

```
UPDATE articulos SET visitas = visitas + 1 WHERE id = 1;
```

No vas a usar variables ni valores específicos, aparte del filtro (WHERE). Entonces, el motor de base de datos va a hacer lo siguiente:

- Buscar la fila de acuerdo a ID especificado (No necesitas un SELECT previo)
- Buscar la columna `visitas` para aplicar el nuevo valor
- Calcular el nuevo valor, como no hay variable, toma lo que hay actualmente en `visitas` e incrementa en 1
- Guardar el nuevo valor

Suponiendo que fuera necesario el SELECT, seguramente ya lo habrías hecho antes para mostrar el artículo.

Comment: Sí que es necesario el select porque mi intención era seleccionar un valor y aumentarlo a la vez, pero al final me han dicho que es imposible, perdón por no explicarme bien.